# How to pass 1 record of app data to a route, in vuejs & vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have (users) data in my main vue app.data . And I want to show data from 1 record  (user)  via a route parameter like `/user/:userid`.

I have been trying a lot of things, but I just started learning vue so it's not clear to me which is the best approach.

I have made a codepen to make things easier :
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NBgyOB?editors=1010

users data looks like this :

```
var data_users = [
  {id:1, name:'john', height:75},
  {id:2, name:'jane', height:75},
  {id:3, name:'alex', height:75},
  {id:4, name:'peter', height:75},
  {id:5, name:'maria', height:75},
]
```

the vue app looks like this :

```
var app = new Vue({
  router,
  data: {
    users: data_users
  }
  ,methods: {
    getUser(id) {
      var one = this.users.filter((d) => {
        return d.id == id;
      });
      return one[0];
    }
  }
}).$mount('#app');
```

I have coded a method to select 1 user from the id:
I don't know if this needs to be a method / a normal function / something else ; or even if this should go in the main app or elsewhere.

and the routes:

```
const User = { 
  props: ['id', 'thisUser'],
  template: `
  <div>
    <h3>User data:</h3>
    <h5>$route.params</h5>
      <p> this user id : {{$route.params.id}} </p>
    <h5>$parent & $root + method + $route.params</h5>
      <p> this user name:    {{$parent.getUser($route.params.id).name}} </p>
      <p> this user height:  {{$root.getUser($route.params.id).height}} </p>

    <h5>'id' prop</h5>
      <p> id : {{id}} </p>

    <h5>'thisUser' prop, = data_users[2]</h5>
      <p> user3 name:    {{thisUser.name}} </p>
      <p> user3 height:  {{thisUser.height}} </p>

    <h5>$parent & $root</h5>
      <p> user1 name:    {{$parent.users[0].name}} </p>
      <p> user1 height:  {{$root.users[0].height}} </p>

  </div> `
}

function dynamicPropsFn (route) {
  const now = new Date()
  return {
    name: (now.getFullYear() + parseInt(route.params.years)) + '!'
  }
}
const routes = [
  { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
  { path: '/bar', component: Bar }
  ,{ path: '/user/:id', component: User, props: {thisUser: data_users[2]} }
  // ,{ path: '/user/:id', component: User, props: {thisUser:getUser(id)} }
]
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes // short for `routes: routes`
})
```

The only way of achieving what I want is via `{{$parent.getUser($route.params.id).name}}` or `{{$root.getUser($route.params.id).name}}`

But I believe that this is running the method unnecessarily each time I display 1 property value. It's also quite long, I suppose there a method that would allow to shorten this to `{{thisUser.name}}`

What would be the best approach to achieve this?

**What I tried so far:**
I have tried to pass the method via `props` but there I can't run the method. I also tried to change the method in a function.

Another way I tried was via `<router-view :thisUser2="'users[3]'"></router-view>`. That almost worked (didn't get the method to work) but it would pass this prop to every route, which is not good. I will have routes which do not need the prop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way is to use a computed property:

```
const User = { 
  props: ['id', 'thisUser'],
  computed:
  {
    userID()
    {
      return Number(this.$route.params.id);
    },
    userData()
    {
      return this.$root.users.find(item => item.id === this.userID);
    }
  },
  template: `
  <div>
    <h3>User data:</h3>
    <h5>$route.params</h5>
      <p> this user id : {{ userID }} </p>
    <h5>$parent & $root + method + $route.params</h5>
      <p> this user name:    {{ userData.name }} </p>
      <p> this user height:  {{ userData.height }} </p>

    <h5>'id' prop</h5>
      <p> id : {{id}} </p>

    <h5>'thisUser' prop, = data_users[2]</h5>
      <p> user3 name:    {{thisUser.name}} </p>
      <p> user3 height:  {{thisUser.height}} </p>

    <h5>$parent & $root</h5>
      <p> user1 name:    {{$parent.users[0].name}} </p>
      <p> user1 height:  {{$root.users[0].height}} </p>

  </div> `
}
```